# Codeignitter route for passing id to controller and from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter

I have a view where I have a Table of Users, which I print with a Loop.
In this Table I have a Link:

```
<a href="<?= base_url('edit_user_id/'.$row->id) ?>" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-edit"></a>
```

In the route-config I have following route

```
$route['edit_user_id/(:num)'] = 'user/edit_user_id/$1';
```

In the Controller user I have the function

```
public function edit_user_id($id){
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('user/edit_user_id/edit_user_id', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Im trying to call the function with an id and pass this to the view where
I want to edit the User with this id

Can someone help me to find my failure?

Solution:

```
$data['id'] = $id;
```

is wrong it has to be

```
$data->id = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

Comment: What is your "failure"? What is not working?

Comment: The View where I print the table is working. The problem is, that I get an fatal error, when I use the link in the table to get the edit-page.

Comment: And what is the "Fatal Error". It will show a few more words than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,`$data['id'] = $id;` is wrong it has to be `$data->id = $this->uri->segment(2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit_user_id($id){

    $this->load->view('user/edit_user_id/edit_user_id', $data);

}
```

check this line of yours